# How to find a number of occurrences of every element of a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

Given an array of integers, I would like to obtain an array of the same size where every value is a number of occurrences of a corresponding element in the original array.

For example given the following array:

```
a = np.array([1, 1, 4, 10, 5, 3, 5, 5, 8, 9])
```

This should be the result:

```
array([2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1])
```

Even though it is straightforward to achieve this via `collections.Counter` or built-in `list.count()`, I'm looking for a more performant way to work with large lists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [`np.unique`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) and use the parameter `return_inverse` and `return_counts`. Use `return_inverse` to index `return_counts` to get desired results.

> **return_inverse** bool, optional
> If True, also return the indices of the unique array (for the specified axis, if provided) that can be used to reconstruct ar.
>
> **return_counts** bool, optional
> If True, also return the number of times each unique item appears in ar.

```
_, idx, c = np.unique(a, return_inverse=True, return_counts=True)
c[idx]
# array([2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1])
```

Answer (score 4):

See [numpy.bincount](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html):

> Count number of occurrences of each value in array of non-negative ints.

Specifically,

```
np.bincount(a)[a]
```

will produce your desired result. `bincount` produces an array that maps every value `0...amax(a)` to the number of occurrences of those values. You do not want to know how many times did 6 or 7 occur. Instead, it looks like you are interested to have a mapping between input values and the number of occurences. This can be achieved by indexing the output from `bincount` with original values from `a`.

#### Test 1:

We get the same result as in the original post:

```
>>> import numpy as np

>>> a = np.array([1, 1, 4, 10, 5, 3, 5, 5, 8, 9])

>>> np.all(np.equal(np.bincount(a)[a], [2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1]))
True
```

#### Test 2

This is a modified timing test from https://stackoverflow.com/a/76444102/8033585

```
import numpy as np
import timeit

TRIALS = 10

a = np.random.randint(1, 1000000, 100000)

def np_bincount_version(a):
    b = np.bincount(a)
    return np.array([b[item] for item in a])

def np_bincount_this_version(a):
    return np.bincount(a)[a]

def np_unique_version(a):
    _, idx, c = np.unique(a, return_inverse=True, return_counts=True)
    return c[idx]

def np_self_compare_version(a):
    return (a[:,None]==a).sum(axis=0)

assert np.all(np.equal(np_bincount_version(a), np_bincount_this_version(a)))
assert (np_bincount_version(a) == np_unique_version(a)).all()
assert (np_unique_version(a)   == np_self_compare_version(a)).all()

np_bincount_version_time = timeit.timeit(stmt='np_bincount_version(a)', number=TRIALS, globals=globals())
np_unique_version_time = timeit.timeit(stmt='np_unique_version(a)', number=TRIALS, globals=globals())
np_bincount_this_version_time = timeit.timeit(stmt='np_bincount_this_version(a)', number=TRIALS, globals=globals())
np_self_compare_version_time = timeit.timeit(stmt='np_self_compare_version(a)', number=TRIALS, globals=globals())

min_time = min([np_bincount_version_time, np_bincount_this_version_time, np_unique_version_time, np_self_compare_version_time])

print('Absolute time:')
print(f'Bincount version: {np_bincount_version_time:.2f} seconds per {TRIALS} runs.')
print(f'**This** Bincount version: {np_bincount_this_version_time:.2f} seconds per {TRIALS} runs.')
print(f'Numpy unique version: {np_unique_version_time:.2f} seconds per {TRIALS} runs.')
print(f'Self compare version: {np_self_compare_version_time:.2f} seconds per {TRIALS} runs.')
print()
print('Normalized time:')
print(f'Bincount version: {np_bincount_version_time / min_time:.2f}x')
print(f'**This** Bincount version: {np_bincount_this_version_time / min_time:.2f}x')
print(f'Numpy unique version: {np_unique_version_time / min_time:.2f}x')
print(f'Self compare version: {np_self_compare_version_time / min_time:.2f}x')

Absolute time:
Bincount version: 0.12 seconds per 10 runs.
**This** Bincount version: 0.01 seconds per 10 runs.
Numpy unique version: 0.08 seconds per 10 runs.
Self compare version: 85.21 seconds per 10 runs.

Normalized time:
Bincount version: 16.25x
**This** Bincount version: 1.00x
Numpy unique version: 10.27x
Self compare version: 11627.32x
```

Comment: I have already tried it, but it doesn't produce the same result as in the example I provided.

Comment: @KonstantinKostanzhoglo `np.bincount(a)[a]`

Comment: It works for the number of occurrences of a particular value, equivalent to built-in `array.count()`, what is the idiomatic way to extend it for the whole array as in my example?

Comment: Can such indexing be achieved via `numpy` instead of a list comprehension such as `b = np.bincount(a); np.array([b[item] for item in a])`?

Comment: @KonstantinKostanzhoglo _"I have already tried it, but it doesn't produce the same result as in the example I provided."_ Yes it does.

Answer (score 2):

Compare the array to itself in a broadcast and add up the True values:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 1, 4, 10, 5, 3, 5, 5, 8, 9])

c = (a[:,None]==a).sum(axis=0)

print(c) # [2 2 1 1 3 1 3 3 1 1]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np

# Declare an array
a = np.array([1, 1, 4, 10, 5, 3, 5, 5, 8, 9])

occurences = []

# Loop thorugh the array
for i in a:
     # Capture elements that are equal to i
     #
     # For example when i = 1, elements = [0, 1]
     # The elements array would contain the indices of all ones present in the array
     #
     elements = np.where(a == i)[0]
     
     # The length of this "elements" array will 
     # be equal to the number of occurences of i in a
     occurences.append(len(elements))

# This can be writen using list comprehension
# occurences = [len(np.where(a == i)[0]) for i in a]
```

Comment: Can you add a brief sentence or two describing your code? Code without an explanation isn't always helpful.

Comment: I hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 1):

Having received as many as three working solutions I decided to check how well they perform by using the following code:

```
import timeit

import numpy as np

TRIALS = 10**6

a = np.array([1, 1, 4, 10, 5, 3, 5, 5, 8, 9])

def np_bincount_version(a):
    b = np.bincount(a)
    return np.array([b[item] for item in a])

def np_unique_version(a):
    _, idx, c = np.unique(a, return_inverse=True, return_counts=True)
    return c[idx]

def np_self_compare_version(a):
    return (a[:,None]==a).sum(axis=0)

assert (np_bincount_version(a) == np_unique_version(a)).all()
assert (np_unique_version(a)   == np_self_compare_version(a)).all()

np_bincount_version_time = timeit.timeit(stmt='np_bincount_version(a)', number=TRIALS, globals=globals())
np_unique_version_time = timeit.timeit(stmt='np_unique_version(a)', number=TRIALS, globals=globals())
np_self_compare_version_time = timeit.timeit(stmt='np_self_compare_version(a)', number=TRIALS, globals=globals())

min_time = min([np_bincount_version_time, np_unique_version_time, np_self_compare_version_time])

print('Absolute time:')
print(f'Bincount version: {np_bincount_version_time:.2f} seconds per {TRIALS} runs.')
print(f'Numpy unique version: {np_unique_version_time:.2f} seconds per {TRIALS} runs.')
print(f'Self compare version: {np_self_compare_version_time:.2f} seconds per {TRIALS} runs.')
print()
print('Normalized time:')
print(f'Bincount version: {np_bincount_version_time / min_time:.2f}x')
print(f'Numpy unique version: {np_unique_version_time / min_time:.2f}x')
print(f'Self compare version: {np_self_compare_version_time / min_time:.2f}x')
```

And the results are the following:

```
Absolute time:
Bincount version: 4.94 seconds per 1000000 runs.
Numpy unique version: 21.02 seconds per 1000000 runs.
Self compare version: 3.74 seconds per 1000000 runs.

Normalized time:
Bincount version: 1.32x
Numpy unique version: 5.61x
Self compare version: 1.00x
```

*(Note that I assume the performance characteristics stay about the same for a different size of an array).*

The solution based on comparing elements to each other seems to perform slightly better than `np.bincount` version, though I use list comprehension in the latter to build a list, which is likely not to be the optimal solution (feel free to post a `numpy` idiomatic version!). Meanwhile `np.unique` version is clearly way behind its competitors.

Comment: *Note that I assume the performance characteristics stay about the same for a different size of an array* That is a bad assumption.  Rerun your timing measurements with a variety of larger inputs.

Comment: @Warren Weckesser
You are absolutely right, thanks for pointing it out to me. After closer examination I found out that `self_compare` version has exponential growth while `bincount` version behaves linearly for any input size and `np_unique` version performs slightly slower for inputs below 1,000 elements and then levels off, working 8x faster than `bincount`. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: My version (`np.bincount(a)[a]`) is about 16x faster than your bincount version and it does produce the same result: `np.all(np.equal(np.bincount(a)[a], np_bincount_version(a)))` returns `True`

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

# Example array
arr = np.array([1, 1, 4, 10, 5, 3, 5, 5, 8, 9])

# Find unique elements and their counts
unique_elements, counts = np.unique(arr, return_counts=True)

# Print the results
for element, count in zip(unique_elements, counts):
    print(f"Element {element} occurs {count} times")
```